# UIView animation to "rewind" a pan gesture: recursion?

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a scenario where the user dragged a UIView somewhere; I want to return it to where it started, and I want it to return along the same track and at the same speed that the user dragged. I have come up with a recursive solution that looks like this:

```
@property (...) NSMutableArray *dragTrack; // recorded during pan gesture

- (void)goHome
{
        [self backtrack: [self.dragTrack count] 
                         withDelay: 1.0 / [self.dragTrack count]];  
                 // interim version of delay; will implement accurate timing later
}

- (void)backtrack: (int)idx withDelay: (double)delay
{
    if (idx > 0){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:delay options: 0
        animations: ^{
            self.center = [[self.dragTrack objectAtIndex:idx - 1] CGPointValue];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [self backtrack: idx - 1 withDelay: delay];
        }];
    } else {
        // do cleanup stuff
    }
}
```

This works, and recursion depth doesn't appear to be an issue - my drag tracks are typically only a couple of hundred points long. (I assume the chances of the recursive call to backtrack getting tail call optimized are rather slim?). But I'm still wondering: is this a reasonable/normal/safe solution to what I'm trying to achieve? Or is there a simpler way to pass a collection of timestamps and states to an animation and say "play these"?

Answer (score 0):

You are **not causing recursion** there. Since the completion block is called asynchronously, it is not getting deeper into function stack. You can see it yourself by setting a breakpoint there and check the stack trace.
You can imagine `NSTimer` there triggering theoretically infinite times and not causing recursion.

To your second question, you can make such animation. It is called `CAKeyframeAnimation` and it is part of `QuartzCore` framework. It would require you to work with layers instead of views, but it is not *that* difficult.

Just one note to your code: try to use option `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` for the animation to be more smooth.